# Loading a saved model in Keras with a custom layer and prediction results are different?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

My network was achieving 96% accuracy on my dataset (edit: on predicting 9 classes). I saved the entire model for every epoch (weights included) whenever I ran it. I ran it 3 times, each time testing different hyperparameters, each time achieving around 96% accuracy.

When I try to load any of these tests now and run it again, it achieves around 50% accuracy. I'm extremely confident I'm running it on the same dataset.

Here's the interesting thing: if I train a new network instance of the exact same architecture, same size, shape, etc., it only ever reaches a max of 85% accuracy. Additionally, saving and loading these new training models works *correctly*, as in the model will reach the same 85% accuracy.

So, there's *no* problem with loading and *no* problem with my dataset. The only way this could happen is if something is wrong in my custom layer, or something else is happening.

Unfortunately I haven't been committing all of my changes to the custom layer to git. While I can't guarantee that my custom layer is the exact same, I'm almost completely confident it is.

Any ideas to what could be causing this discrepancy?

Edit: To add more context, the layer is ripped from the ConvLSTM2d class but I replaced the call() function to simply be a vanilla RNN that uses convolution instead of the dot product. I *am* confident that the call() function is the same as before, but I am not confident that the rest of the class is the same. Is there anything else in the class that could affect performance? I've checked activation function already.

Comment: Different initializations may generate different performance, it could be that your previous attempts went well due to good initial weights and thus escaped from a suboptimal performance.

Comment: 1. Keras version 2. Which format are you saving your model (JSON/YAML) and your weights (HD5) 3. Can you share some of your code?

Comment: @spicyramen 1) keras.__version__ says 2.2.0, 2) I didn't know there were 2 things to save. I use the  ModelCheckpoint() callback, it saves weights as HD5. To rerun the code I supply the custom layer via custom_objects dict in load_model(), 3) sure - what would you like to see? Traveling for the next couple days so I am limited in access to code.

Comment: @lintang Would initializations affect a saved model? If so, how can I check for that?

Comment: @santasmic, no, weight initialization parameters don't affect weights from saved models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *finally* found the answer.

I have implemented a custom Lambda layer to handle reshaping. This layer has difficulties loading. Specifically, it reshapes one dimension into two dimensions on an arbitrary interval. The interval was defaulting to one specific value every time I loaded the model, even though it was incorrect. When I force it to be the correct interval, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let´s think about it, there are basically two possible reasons for your problem. Your custom layer is not the same and therefore some weights are not set up correctly, which leads to missclassification. In case of a binary classification you will end up in 50% accuracy on balanced data.

The second possible reason is, that threre is a bug in keras serialization. In this case your new trained and saved models should also show this issue, after deserialization.

> While I can't guarantee that my custom layer is the exact same, I'm almost completely confident it is.

So the problem is not reproducable with a new model, you accuracy is 50% and you cannot guarantee that the custom layer matches. -> I guess it is you custom layer.

Comment: I could have worded it better - so, I'm 100% confident that the call() function of the custom layer is the exact same. It's just a vanilla recurrent neural net, but with convolution. This is ripped from the ConvLSTM2d class - I copied that class and implemented a custom call. To be more clear, what I'm asking is: is there anything besides the call() function that could affect performance of a saved model?

Comment: Also - the dataset I'm testing on has 9 classes. So, 50% performance is doing something, but that something is not what it was doing before. I've checked that it's loading the weights correctly and it seems to be.

Comment: Ok, but you said you can not reproduce it with your recently trained networks? So this happens only to the one single model which has been trained with some code, which you can not revert to, right?

Comment: Another bit of information is that at the time of the successful network, I also trained a network with a different architecture (vanilla LSTM) and it was very much not successful. Attempting to train with a vanilla LSTM now achieves great success. It has to be an external factor. However, I think this question is too general and nobody can really help me without knowing everything involved, so I'll probably close it.